# Laravel Query whereHas and whereIn

Tags: php, laravel

In my code I'm applying multiple search filters. Below is the core part where I don't get the expected result.

The result should be users that have a specific post connected to it or no posts connected to it (as expected through `whereHas`) AND has a specific status (example below `available_now`).

But the below query results also gives the specific result type where the user has a specific post connected (expected) but the result includes users with a status other than `available_now` (unexpected).

I would like the query to apply both conditions. Am I missing something?

```
$users = User::query();

$users = $this->filter1($users);
$users = $this->filter2($users);

private static function filter1($users) {
    $post_id = 5;

    $users->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($post_id) {
        $query->where('id', $post_id);
    })->orDoesntHave('posts');

   return $users;
}

private static function filter2($users) {
    $availability = array('available_now');
    $users->whereIn('availability', $availability); // I'm using whereIn because in some cases the $availability array has multiple values

    return $users;
}

return $users->get();
```

Comment: Look at the SQL code this generates. You probably have a problem with evaluation order (`whereHas OR doesntHave AND whereIn` - if the part before `OR` evaluates to true, the rest of the expression is insignificant).

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated the question to show how the search filters are separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the `orDoesntHave`. Make use of the parenthesis in your query to make sure your conditions work as expected:

```
$users = User::query();

$users = $this->filter1($users);
$users = $this->filter2($users);

private static function filter1($users) {
    $post_id = 5;

    $users->where(function ($query) use ($post_id) { //Will add parenthesis around this part of the query
        $query->whereHas('posts', function ($subquery) use ($post_id) {
            $subquery->where('id', $post_id);
        })->orDoesntHave('posts');
    });

   return $users;
}

private static function filter2($users) {
    $availability = array('available_now');
    $users->whereIn('availability', $availability);

    return $users;
}

return $users->get();
```

Comment: As I have multiple other search filters I'm keeping them separate so I can't chain them, I've updated the question to show how they're separated.

Comment: @SystemGlitch I think the point of separating the filters to separate methods is that the filters can be used separately, which is not possible after moving part of one filter to the other one.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký Combining `whereHas` and `orDoesntHave` on the same table makes it useless because always true. That's why it needs to be separated and inside parenthesis. Maybe I didn't correclty understand what the OP needs exactly?

Comment: @SystemGlitch That is not true. "has posts with some specific id OR has no posts" is a perfectly valid non-tautological expression.

Comment: I updated my answer to better fit the expected result.

Comment: @SystemGlitch thanks for your updated answer. One comment; if what you‘re saying is true (combination of whereHas and orDoesntHave is causing the unexpected result), then it’s still weird that filter2 is not applied (which is the described problem) as it’s separate from filter1. I can’t test your code atm as I’m on my phone so will check tomorrow.

Comment: @eskimo As Martin said, it's actually false. I didn't consider the condition inside `whereHas`. The problem was that if the `whereHas` condition was met, the rest of the query wasn't interpreted: `whereAs OR doesntHave AND whereIn`.